# form wont send data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to code a form that gets some data from a mysql db, and the rest i have to fill inn myself. The problem is that in add.php witch insert to mysql dont get data from the form.
My codes are:

```
    <form action="add.php" method="post">
                <table border="0px" align="center" width="300px">

                <tr align="center">
                <td><h2>Flight</h2></td>
                <td><h2>Org</h2></td>
                <td><h2>Dest</h2></td>
                <td><h2>STD</h2></td>
                <td><h2>ATD</h2></td>
                <td><h2>Delay</h2></td>
                <td><h2>NET</h2></td>
                <td><h2>Gros</h2></td>
                <td><h2>Core Material</h2></td>
                <td><h2>ACS</h2></td>
                <td><h2>Total sorted</h2></td>

                </tr>
                <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db","pass") or die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$q="SELECT flightnr, org, dest, std FROM flight";
$sql = mysql_query($q) or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                        $flightnr2 = $row['flightnr'];
        $org2 = $row['org'];
        $dest2 = $row['dest'];
        $std2 = $row['std'];
                        }
                        ?>
                             <tr>
                             <td><input type="text" name="flightnr" value="<?php echo $flightnr2;?>" /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="org" id="org" value="<?php echo $org2;?>" /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="dest" id="dest" value="<?php echo $dest2;?>" /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="std" id="std" value="<?php echo $std2;?>" /></td>
                             <td><input type="time" name="adt" id="adt" placeholder="ATD"></td>
                             <td><input type="time" name="delay" id="delay" placeholder="Delay"></td>
                             <td><input type="int" name="net" id="net" placeholder="NET"></td>
                             <td><input type="int" name="gros" id="gros" placeholder="Gros"></td>
                             <td><input type="int" name="core" id="core" placeholder="Core Material"></td>
                             <td><input type="int" name="acs" id="acs" placeholder="ACS"></td>
                             <td><input type="int" name="tot" id="tot" placeholder="Total sorted"></td>
                             <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </form>
```

add.php:

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","db","pass") or die('Could not connect: '  .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db", $con) or die(mysql_error());

$date = date("D-m-Y");
$flightnr = $_POST['flightnr'];
$org = $_POST['org'];
$dest = $_POST['dest'];
$std = $_POST['dest'];
$adt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adt']);
$delay = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delay']);
$net = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['net']);
$gros = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gros']);
$core = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['core']);
$acs = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acs']);
$tot = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tot']);

$sql="INSERT INTO fly (date, flightnr, org, dest, std, adt, delay, net, gros, core, acs, tot)VALUES('$date', '$flightnr', '$org', '$std', '$adt', '$delay', '$net', '$gros', '$core', '$acs', '$tot')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Any idea how I can get it to work...

Comment: Where did you learn to program forms like this? I'm curious. I see a lot of code like this on Stack Overflow and want to know where people are getting their references.

Comment: I've tried several things in my code.., removed som errors.., and got some new.. :P I think I have done something right.., and got the info over to add.php. But I get error when i run the script. Can someone look over the files and see what i've done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In add.php you're checking $row instead of $_POST.
It should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['atd']) && isset($_POST['..']) && ... )
{
    $values = Array($_POST['atd'], $_POST['..'], ...);
    $values = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $values);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO fly (date, flightnr, org, dest, std, adt, delay, net, gros, core, asc, tot) VALUES ('" . implode(',', $values) . "');";
}
```

Anyway you should use PDO or MySQLi because MySQL is deprecated.

Comment: You **must** escape that. What you're doing here is reckless.

Comment: The original question makes liberal use of `mysql_real_escape_string`, which is the least you should do, and you've somehow removed that and introduced a giant [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Now you're escaping the whole thing, embedding the commas. This is even worse than before. What you need is [`array_map`](http://ca1.php.net/array_map) if you're going to advocate this bulk approach.

Comment: Clunky, though much better. That's why using `mysql_query` is a pain and yet another reason to use PDO, as you've pointed out.

Comment: all miss spellings are fixed in my first post. And I've tried to use the code from AleVale.. but nothing happends when i hit submit button...

Comment: Have you executed the query after initialized it? After $sql = ".."; you should have written mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); When I put this in the code after } i get error" Undefined variable: sql in add.php on line 13 Query was empty<br> if I put it in before } I get nothing.

Comment: You have to put in the if (...) { } right after $sql. You get this error because the variable $sql is not defined out that scope. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp see the part where it talks about "variables scope".

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of miss spelling and mistakes here.. take a look at this:

```
echo '<td><input type="int" name="acs" id="acs" placeholder="ACS"></td>'
```

and

```
$asc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['asc']);
```

So you realy have to read your codes, and check your spelling.

Here is one more:

`$dest = $row['dest'];`

`$std = $row['dest'];`

This should be like this:

```
$dest = $row['dest'];
$std = $row['std'];
```

Answer (score 0):

in your form add hidden field like
    ">
in your add.php file get your data like
$flightner=$_POST['flightnr'];
then fire sql query insert into..

```
    <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="<?php echo $row['flightnr'];?>"/>
```

Hi.. xzibiz
First,you have to store a value $row['flightnr'] in specific hidden field then use $_POST['test'] to fetch actual value

```
    $flightnr=$_POST['test'];
```

Reason for error...
php only reads those data which sent by html input field so you can fetch those value from inputed field html using php server variable $_REQUEST['html_input_field']

Comment: I've read about hidden fields.., but i cant find out what you mean. If i pull out my data with $flightnr=$_POST['flightnr']; i get error: Undefined index: flightnr

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now.. my new code is:

```
$q="SELECT flightnr, org, dest, std FROM flight";
$sql = mysql_query($q) or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
        $flightnr2 = $row['flightnr'];
        $org2 = $row['org'];
        $dest2 = $row['dest'];
        $std2 = $row['std'];
                        }
                        ?>
                             <tr>
                             <td><input type="text" name="flightnr" value="<?php echo $flightnr2;?>" /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="org" id="org" value="<?php echo $org2;?>" /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="dest" id="dest" value="<?php echo $dest2;?>" /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="std" id="std" value="<?php echo $std2;?>" /></td>
```

add.php:

```
$date = date("D-m-Y");
$flightnr = $_POST['flightnr'];
$org = $_POST['org'];
$dest = $_POST['dest'];
$std = $_POST['dest'];
$adt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adt']);
$delay = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delay']);
$net = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['net']);
$gros = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gros']);
$core = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['core']);
$acs = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acs']);
$tot = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tot']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO fly ".
"(date, flightnr, org, dest, std, adt, delay, net, gros, core, acs, tot) ".
"VALUES ('$date', '$flightnr', '$org', '$dest', '$std', '$adt', '$delay', '$net', '$gros', '$core', '$acs', '$tot')";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```